# Multiple aggregation in group by in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, aggregate-functions

```
SQL : Select Max(A) , Min (B) , C from Table group by C
```

I want to do the same operation in pandas on a dataframe. The closer I got was till :

```
DF2= DF1.groupby(by=['C']).max()
```

where I land up getting max of both the columns , how do i do more than one operation while grouping by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `agg()` function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(20, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
print(df)

print(df.groupby('C').agg({'A': max, 'B':min}))
```

Output:

```
    A  B  C
0   2  3  0
1   2  2  1
2   4  0  1
3   0  1  4
4   3  3  2
5   0  4  3
6   2  4  2
7   3  4  0
8   4  2  2
9   3  2  1
10  2  3  1
11  4  1  0
12  4  3  2
13  0  0  1
14  3  1  1
15  4  1  1
16  0  0  0
17  4  0  1
18  3  4  0
19  0  2  4
   A  B
C
0  4  0
1  4  0
2  4  2
3  0  4
4  0  1
```

Alternatively you may want to check [pandas.read_sql_query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html) function...

Answer (score 3):

You can use function [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
DF2 = DF1.groupby('C').agg({'A': max, 'B': min})
```

Sample:

```
print DF1
   A   B  C  D
0  1   5  a  a
1  7   9  a  b
2  2  10  c  d
3  3   2  c  c

DF2 = DF1.groupby('C').agg({'A': max, 'B': min})

print DF2
   A  B
C      
a  7  5
c  3  2
```

[GroupBy-fu: improvements in grouping and aggregating data in pandas](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/)  - nice explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [agg](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.groupby('something').agg({'column1': np.max, 'columns2': np.min})
```