# Python - Group-by multiple columns with .mean() and .agg()

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, mean

I want to group-by three columns, and then find the mean of a fourth numerical column for all rows which are duplicated across the first three columns. I can achieve this with the following function:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False)['col4'].mean()
```

The problem is that I also want a fifth column which will aggregate for all rows grouped by the groupby function, which I don't know how to do on top of the previous function. For example:

```
df 
index    col1        col2       col3       col4       col5
0        Week_1      James      John       1          when and why?
1        Week_1      James      John       3          How?
2        Week_2      James      John       2          Do you know when?
3        Week_2      Mark       Jim        3          What time?
4        Week_2      Andrew     Simon      1          How far is it?
5        Week_2      Andrew     Simon      2          Are you going?


CURRENT(with above function):
index    col1        col2       col3       col4
0        Week_1      James      John       2
1        Week_2      James      John       2
2        Week_2      Mark       Jim        3
3        Week_2      Andrew     Simon      1.5

DESIRED:
index    col1        col2       col3       col4       col5
0        Week_1      James      John       2          when and why?, How?
2        Week_2      James      John       2          Do you know when?
3        Week_2      Mark       Jim        3          What time?
4        Week_2      Andrew     Simon      1.5        How far is it?, Are you going?
```

I've tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901959/multiple-aggregation-in-group-by-in-pandas-dataframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409180/create-two-aggregate-columns-by-group-by-pandas), however the .mean() function I'm using complicates the process. Any help would be appreciated. (If possible, I would like to specify a custom delimiter separating the strings of col5 when aggregated).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define for each column aggregate function:

```
df2=df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'], as_index=False).agg({'col4':'mean', 'col5':','.join})
print (df2)
     col1    col2   col3  col4                           col5
0  Week_1   James   John   2.0             when and why?,How?
1  Week_2  Andrew  Simon   1.5  How far is it?,Are you going?
2  Week_2   James   John   2.0              Do you know when?
3  Week_2    Mark    Jim   3.0                     What time?
```

General solution is numeric columns aggregate by `mean` and other by `join`:

```
f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ', '.join(x)
df2 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False).agg(f)
print (df2)

     col1    col2   col3  col4                            col5
0  Week_1   James   John   2.0             when and why?, How?
1  Week_2  Andrew  Simon   1.5  How far is it?, Are you going?
2  Week_2   James   John   2.0               Do you know when?
3  Week_2    Mark    Jim   3.0                      What time?
```

Comment: @LaurieBamber - Thank you, for you too :)